# Socket closed error when running sonar from maven

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've been encountering a socket closed error every time I try to analyze our project from my PC. I have installed SonarQube on a server within our network because we have plans to integrate it into our development process and we are now currently on the testing stage. Here is the error from web.log

```
2017.08.15 08:08:20 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.08.15 08:08:22 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\sonarqube-6.2\web
2017.08.15 08:08:23 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8085"]
2017.08.15 08:08:23 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.08.15 08:08:38 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [Burner] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2017.08.15 08:08:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9005]
2017.08.15 08:08:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.2 / 4a28f29f95254b58f3cf0a0871bc632e998403f5
2017.08.15 08:08:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2017.08.15 08:08:49 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: C:\sonarqube-6.2\data
2017.08.15 08:08:49 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2017.08.15 08:08:50 WARN  web[][o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2017.08.15 08:08:55 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: C:\sonarqube-6.2
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.5.1.522 / 9a3e26d7843b226a6772b5103e72120c3003d958
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin GitHub / 1.4.0.699 / d953e9749d7f3b6def56f38382dac43a58e7f628
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 4.5.0.8398 / f5a869c42a13d27735d57da1691ca167093a885b
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.18.0.3454 / c276cc8dfeb99da907f2ec76ede9f59836da2bc9
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2017.08.15 08:08:57 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.5.0.476 / 636872f5d37fa7a440fe07d08d504e1a881225e5
2017.08.15 08:09:03 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2017.08.15 08:09:10 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2017.08.15 08:09:13 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2017.08.15 08:09:13 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2017.08.15 08:09:14 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2017.08.15 08:09:19 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2017.08.15 08:09:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2017.08.15 08:09:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2017.08.15 08:09:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index authorization
2017.08.15 08:09:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2017.08.15 08:09:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2017.08.15 08:09:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2017.08.15 08:09:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2017.08.15 08:09:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index project measures
2017.08.15 08:09:29 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_91-b14 [Windows 7-amd64]
2017.08.15 08:09:29 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2017.08.15 08:09:57 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2017.08.15 08:09:58 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@4c7cfbaf [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@5d811cd1]
2017.08.15 08:09:58 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@3179d14a [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@1af3e549]
2017.08.15 08:09:58 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@3ce5c897 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@4369bdc0]
2017.08.15 08:09:58 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction@132a768c [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@1da35e94]
2017.08.15 08:09:58 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.ValidateAction@399b2171 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@79c5aed8]
2017.08.15 08:09:59 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-8085"]
2017.08.15 08:09:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.08.15 08:09:59 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 8085
2017.08.15 09:52:20 ERROR web[AV3jePnruIhnvgU/AAAk][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://192.10.10.110:8085/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.cpi:Geniisys&projectName=Geniisys&projectBranch=Jerome_Cris_Bautista
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readPart(ServletRequest.java:102)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readInputStreamParam(ServletRequest.java:85)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.paramAsInputStream(ValidatingRequest.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:108)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2849)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3151)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readParam(ServletRequest.java:74)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.readParamOrDefaultValue(ValidatingRequest.java:143)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:98)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:70)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.Request.mandatoryParam(Request.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:82)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:375)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
2017.08.15 10:51:31 ERROR web[AV3jePnruIhnvgU/AAAv][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://192.10.10.110:8085/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.cpi:Geniisys&projectName=Geniisys&projectBranch=Jerome_Cris_Bautista
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readPart(ServletRequest.java:102)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readInputStreamParam(ServletRequest.java:85)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.paramAsInputStream(ValidatingRequest.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:108)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2849)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3151)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readParam(ServletRequest.java:74)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.readParamOrDefaultValue(ValidatingRequest.java:143)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:98)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:70)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.Request.mandatoryParam(Request.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:82)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:375)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
2017.08.15 11:36:50 ERROR web[AV3jePnruIhnvgU/AAA6][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://192.10.10.110:8085/api/ce/submit?projectKey=com.cpi:Geniisys&projectName=Geniisys&projectBranch=Jerome_Cris_Bautista
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't read file part
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readPart(ServletRequest.java:102)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readInputStreamParam(ServletRequest.java:85)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.paramAsInputStream(ValidatingRequest.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:108)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:74)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2849)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3151)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readParam(ServletRequest.java:74)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.readParamOrDefaultValue(ValidatingRequest.java:143)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:98)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:70)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.Request.mandatoryParam(Request.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:82)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2776)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:202)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:231)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:414)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:350)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:375)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:850)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

I use the following:

> JRE - 1.8.0_91
>
> SonarQube - 6.2
>
> Maven - 3.3.1

Using the command

```
mvn -Dsonar.branch="Jerome_Cris_Bautista" -Dsonar.sources=src/main -Dsonar.host.url=http://myhost:8085 sonar:sonar
```

I've tried exempting the port that SonarQube uses from the server and increasing the default memory allocation for sonar.web.javaOpt but it didn't work. Can you guys help me out? I can't seem to find the root cause of the error. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the file contents cannot be submitted from the machine, where you run your analysis, to the server, where SonarQube runs. Do you have any firewall/virus scanner inbetween? Or do you use http for an https port?

Comment: Yes, there is an anti-virus installed on my PC. My firewall is also up. I use an http port (8085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by turning off my anti-virus, it seems that it's blocking any outgoing request/files from my PC to the server therefore causing the socket closed error.